# Azure SQL login as Rest-API authenticated user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I am building a WebApp in Azure and the users log in in their App, thorugh their Azure account. The WebApp frontend is sending a Bearer authentication token to the backend so that the backend can authenticate and authorize the users.

I would like to use this token in order to create a database connection to an Azure SQL database on behalf of the user, but I am completely lost. Is there any way to login to the SQL database as the WebApp user?

The backend is in C#.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is in fact possible. The reading list would involve:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

...and the most helpful practical advice I've found:

- https://winterdom.com/2017/08/31/token-delegation-azure-sql